# How can "from A.B import *" be interpreted?

Tags: python

I encountered a snippet of code like:

```
  from object_recognition_msgs.msg import *
```

In my opinion, this but I found there's no msg.py in object_recognition_msgs(which is a directory),
however, there's a directory named "msg" in object_recognition_msgs, the structure of the directory is

```
  object_recognition_msgs
  ├── msg
      ├── __init__.py
      ├── _ObjectId.py
      ├── _ObjectInformation.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionActionFeedback.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionActionGoal.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionAction.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionActionResult.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionFeedback.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionGoal.py
      ├── _ObjectRecognitionResult.py
      ├── _RecognizedObjectArray.py
      ├── _RecognizedObject.py
      ├── _TableArray.py
      └── _Table.py
```

I interpreted "from object_recognition_msgs.msg import *" as importing all python files in object_recognition_msgs/msg, is this interpretation correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement would import all names from the `__init__.py` module in the package, not the files contained.

You'd have to import each module in the package in the `__init__.py` file explicitly for the `*` to import everything in all the modules in the package.

Answer (score 1):

Because `msg` is a directory, the import statement will execute the file `msg/__init__.py` and import all non-private names defined in that file.  It will not import any other files, unless `msg/__init__.py` imports them itself.